# Do I need full Google Drive permission in order to overwrite a file?

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api

This was originally posted and closed at [WebApps SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/146328/74602). I repost here hoping it's on-topic.

> I have tried "Scan to Cloud" on my Epson WorkForce EF-2660 to scan
> documents directly to Google Drive.
>
> It works fine, but I had to stop doing it because Epson Connect
> requires the following permissions:
>
> View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or
> created with this app See, edit, create, and delete all of your Google
> Drive files
> #1 is fine, and I see why they need it. I am not comfortable with #2.
>
> Epson user support writes that they need #2 in order to "replace the
> old file in case I scan another file with the same name" (translation
> mine). This is not convincing to me: First, can they really not delete
> a file they created with #1? Second, doesn't Google Drive support
> multiple files with the same name?

Rephrasing this: if my I want an app to be able to create files and later overwrite them, do I need to grant the `drive` permission, or should `drive.file` be enough?

Comment: You are aware that you can't change the authorization scopes of "Scan to cloud", right?

Comment: @Rubén yes, unfortunately.